How to recover Google Analytics Account From Trash?
We accidentally moved one of our Google Analytics accounts to Trash, but now in Trash, we cannot see that account so that we can restore it.
Do you guys have an idea how to make it visible over there or have any contact email or phone number so that we can connect to the Google Analytics team?

Are you sure you are performing these actions from an administrator account? If yes, and the Trash is still empty, reach out to Google Support.
Typically, data can be restored within 35 days, but if that time has passed, the account and data are permanently deleted.

35 days are not over and now we can see the account in Trash, for three days the Trash Can was not showing any data.
I found it in Trash Can today and restored it successfully, but we have lost 3 days of data.
Thank you for your answer.
